# Conditional Compilation in Haskell submodule

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to have a submodule in my program compile conditionally to switch small parts of the code between release builds and development builds.

Currently I'm attempting to use [cpphs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cpphs-1.17/src/docs) however when I change the flags passed into GHC to define a variable and change an ifdef statement stack won't recompile those files.

For example, I've got a port number that I want to switch based on which target I have built. The code I have defining this number looks like this.

```
#ifdef StableRelease 
  port = 12345
#else 
  port = 54321 
#endif
```

the stable build has the following options in its cabal file

```
ghc-options: -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N -pgmP cpphs -optP "-DStableRelease"
```

When I run `stack build` though it doesn't seem to actually pre-process the code above.
Does anyone have experience with cpphs or another preprocessing solution?

Comment: Did you include `{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}` in the module of interest?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Yes I have included the CPP language extension in the file.

Answer (score 5):

I would solve this with the help of flags

### `cppstuf.cabal`-file

```
name:                cppstuf
version:             0.1.0.0
...
cabal-version:       >=1.10

flag StableRelease {
  Description: Stable release settings like port ...
  Default:     False
  }

executable cppstuf
  main-is:             Main.hs
  build-depends:       base >=4.9 && <5.00
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  extensions: CPP
  if flag(StableRelease) {
    GHC-Options: -DSTABLE
  }
```

### `Main.hs`

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main =
#if STABLE
  putStrLn "Hello, Haskell!"
#else
  putStrLn "Hello, Haskell?"
#endif
```

and compiling it

```
stack build
```

or

```
stack build --flag cppstuf:stablerelease
```

### Personal Note aside from the answer

I would not use CPP to manage configuration options - either providing command-line options I like [optparse-applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative) but there is also [cmdargs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cmdargs),and or a configuration file I have used <strike>[configurator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/configurator) for that</strike>, but there are several options out there on hackage. One being [configurator-ng](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/configurator-ng) as @Shersh said - the other one is not being developed anymore.

`CPP` on the other hand I tend to use for making libraries work across multiple GHC/library versions.

### Update - w\ regards to the comment.

- If I deliver a program, the operations team should be able to change ports, hostname or handle file location of input files etc. without knowing haskell let alone recompiling a project.
- It makes error chasing a lot easier if your production source code does not differ from your development sources, say you would have a postgres db in dev mode, but an oracle in production - you'll never find the oracle specific bug.
- For things like optimization levels - I don't mind too much.
- But make sure you test multi-threaded stuff properly, I once ran out of file handles because I was opening a lot but not closing fast enough - If your dev-setting is single threaded you'll deliver a bug.

Comment: Thanks, out of curiosity why would you avoid using CPP like this? If I have multiple modules that will need to change based on being a release or not isn't it easier to adjust these at compile time rather than passing a variable through the whole program?

Comment: You can also combine cabal flags with the following approach in order to get rid of CPP altogether in many cases http://blog.haskell-exists.com/yuras/posts/stop-abusing-cpp-in-haskell.html

Comment: Also, don't use `configurator`. It's outdated and not maintained. use `configurator-ng` instead: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/configurator-ng